# zsh does not reload functions in the prompt

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt, function

I am trying to make the zsh prompt reload a function everytime a new prompt loads. The function outputs a version of `pwd` but shorter, if the output of `pwd` was `~/Downloads/Folder` the function would output `~/D/Folder`. The function works but does not reload if I change directories. This is an issue with zsh and not with the function because the function works fine in ksh and csh. I do not use oh-my-zsh. The function is `_collapsed_pwd` and the file is `$SHELLDIR/cpwdrc`.

Here is my `.zshrc` file

```
export SHELLDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/shells"
export ZSH="$SHELLDIR/zsh"
export HISTFILE="$XDG_DATA_HOME"/zsh/history

autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
fpath=($ZSH/plugins/zsh-completions/src $fpath)
compinit -d $XDG_CACHE_HOME/zsh/zcompdump-artix-5.8

source $SHELLDIR/aliasrc
source $SHELLDIR/colorsrc # contians color substituions

source $SHELLDIR/cpwdrc # contains _collapsed_pwd

source $ZSH/plugins/fzf-tab/fzf-tab.zsh
source $ZSH/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

setopt prompt_subst

PS1=$(printf "${BOLD}${BLUE}%s${NORM}@%s:[${BLUE}%s${NORM}]:$ " $USER $(hostname) $(_collapsed_pwd) )
```

Here is the code for the function `_collapsed_pwd`

```
#!/bin/sh
## Collapsed Directory
_collapsed_pwd() {
  pwd | perl -pe '
   BEGIN {
      binmode STDIN,  ":encoding(UTF-8)";
      binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   }; s|^$ENV{HOME}|~|g; s|/([^/.])[^/]*(?=/)|/$1|g; s|/\.([^/])[^/]*(?=/)|/.$1|g
'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the content of the prompt once and for all when `.zshrc` is processed. There is nothing in your code that says to change the content of the prompt when the current directory changes.

One solution is to put the code to change the prompt in a [`chpwd` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd). Remove `setopt prompt_subst` since you won't be doing any evaluation of the content of `PS1`.

```
function set_prompt {
  PS1=$(printf "${BOLD}${BLUE}%s${NORM}@%s:[${BLUE}%s${NORM}]:$ " $USER $(hostname) "${$(_collapsed_pwd)//\%/%%}" )
}
chpwd_functions+=(set_prompt)
cd .
```

Explanations:

- `cd .` triggers the `chpwd` hook once when zsh starts so as to set the prompt initially.
- The double quotes around the command substitution prevents it from being split into separate word if the output contains whitespace.
- The `${…//\%/%%}` substitution around the output of `_collapsed_pwd` changes `%` to `%%` because `%` would be interpreted as a [prompt escape](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Expansion-of-Prompt-Sequences)¹.

Alternatively, do set the [`prompt_subst` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) and set `PS1` to a string that contains code which will be evaluated each time the prompt is displayed.

```
setopt prompt_subst
PS1='$(printf "${BOLD}${BLUE}%s${NORM}@%s:[${BLUE}%s${NORM}]:$ " $USER $(hostname) "${$(_collapsed_pwd)//\%/%%}" )'
```

You can simplify this a lot by using zsh's [built-in features to include variable data in the prompt](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Expansion-of-Prompt-Sequences). To start with, here's a prompt that displays the last two components of the current directory:

```
unsetopt prompt_subst
PS1='%B%F{blue}%n%f%b@%m:[%F{blue}%2~%f]:%(!.#.$) '
```

To abbreviate directory components, I think you have to run some zsh code, either through a `chpwd` hook or through `prompt_subst`. To avoid complexity related to expansion, use a `chpwd` hook to set `psvar` and [`%v`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#index-psvar_002c-use-of) to refer to `psvar` in the prompt string.

```
unsetopt prompt_subst
PS1='%B%F{blue}%n%f%b@%m:[%F{blue}%1v%f]:%(!.#.$) '
function abbreviate_pwd {
  psvar[1]=${(%):-%~}
  while [[ $psvar[1] =~ /[^/][^/]+/ ]]; do
    psvar[1]=${psvar[1][1,MBEGIN+1]}${psvar[1][MEND,-1]}
  done
}
chpwd_functions+=(abbreviate_pwd)
cd .
```

¹  <sub>For extra robustness, `$USER` (see also `$USERNAME` automatically set by `zsh`) and `$(hostname)` (see also `$HOST` automatically set by `zsh`) should also be protected, but they normally don't contain any of the problematic characters, assuming that you don't change the value of `IFS` to include a character that appears in the host name.</sub>

Comment: When I ran the first and second answers I got an error with the flags so I ran the second with `"$(_collapsed_pwd)"` instead of `"${(_collapsed_pwd)//\%/%%}"` and it works. The last answer also works but I wanted to use the code I had because I use both ksh and zsh and the last answer does not work in ksh.